# Incrementar ViewBag no .cshtml

Tags: c#

Preciso incrementar minha `ViewBag` na minha página `.cshtml`, para a minha `PartialView`
no meu `Controller` eu inicío ela: `ViewBag.count = 0`

Na minha pagina `.cshtml` preciso incrementar:
**exemplo**:

```
@{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     ViewBag.count = i;
     Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Endereco", Model.Enderecos[@i]);
}
}
```

minha `PartialView:`

```
<div id="telefone-@ViewBag.count"></div>
```

seguinte erro ocorre:

```
O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção
```

Comment: Acho que teria que colocar o @ antes do FOR... ALGO ASSIM @{ for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    ViewBag.count = i
}
}

Comment: @PauloHDSousa vou implementar mais a pergunta, obrigado por responder

Comment: funcionou o que eu falei? @Furlan

Comment: @PauloHDSousa outro erro ocorreu

Comment: Então, acontece que dentro de Model.Enderecos[] a quantidade de elementos é menor do que está sendo passado no I,  Outro ponto... Passa assim -> Model.Enderecos[i]);

Comment: usa foreach meu querido!

Comment: Acho bem melhor  adica do @RBoschini

Comment: @RBoschini como ficaria usando `foreach` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo assim:

no meu controller, iniciei minha `viewbag`:

```
ViewBag.count = 0;
```

na view:

```
@foreach (var telefone in Model.Telefones)
{
    @Html.Partial("Telefone", telefone)
}
```

Comment: Edita sua pergunta com esses dados, nao poste uma resposta.

Comment: @RBoschini Pelo incrível que pareça, essa é realmente a resposta para o problema dele.

Answer (score 2):

Lógica de negócio em *View* é uma **péssima** prática, sobretudo porque `ViewBag` é um objeto auxiliar para transportar valores do *Controller* para a *View*.

Se você realmente precisa de variáveis em *View*, use variáveis normais do .NET na sua lógica. Se você precisa passar dados de uma *View* para uma *PartialView*, deve fazer por *ViewModels*, e não pela `ViewBag`.

Este trecho pode ser perfeitamente escrito da seguinte forma:

```
@for (var enderecoObjeto in Model.Enderecos.Select((endereco, i) => new {endereco, i}))
{
     @Html.Partial("EditorTemplates/Endereco", enderecoObjeto);
}
```

A *Partial* pode ter `@model dynamic` ou você pode tipar o objeto com o `i` usando *ViewModel*.

Comment: Cara, eu posso propor códigos assim para a galera que pergunta? Eu geralmente concerto os erros do código mesmo quando poderia ser feito 100x melhor, eu posso fazer isso então né? @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: Você até pode consertar, mas o código é ruim mesmo na formulação dele. Não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Eu fico meio sei la em alterar código alheio, mas obrigado pela informação. @Cigano Morrison Mendez